# Replacing texts in PHP or JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

**html:**

```
<td id="tab"><a href="?title="/>link</a><cite>1</cite><br>hello<br></td>
<td id="tab"><a href="?title="/>link</a><cite>2</cite><br>bye<br></td>
```

**results:**

```
<td id="tab"><a href="?title=hello"/>link</a><cite>1</cite><br><br></td>
<td id="tab"><a href="?title=bye"/>link</a><cite>2</cite><br><br></td>
```

how can i do this job by PHP or JQUERY?

Comment: Maybe you should try to use JavaScript to do this since it is more or less a client side thing  as you want to `move text`

Comment: Looks like a bad design to me.

Comment: i don't know but there is a way to do

Comment: If you have to do this, use Javascript instead !

Comment: how can i do it by javascript?

Comment: all this codes are in google search source and i cant change their id.

Comment: Imagine you wanna cut `hello` and put it in front of `title=`. but how? it doesnt matter with what! `PHP` or `JQUERY` you can use.

Comment: all responses from google search are very structured. It seems your issue is in the code that processes those responses and that you are looking for a hack to fix it. Fix the code that generates the poor output

Comment: i got google's results but they dont have anylink for direct image url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about that, but you can try this :

```
$html = '<td id="tab"><a href="?title="/>link</a><cite>1</cite><br>hello<br></td>';
$html = preg_replace('/^<(\w.*)(<cite>[\d+]<\/cite>)<br>(.*)<br><\/td>$/', '<td id="tab"><a href="?title=$3"/>link</a>$2<br><br></td>', $html);
```

Comment: I forget to do the same for <city>